# BLE emission when disconnected and waiting connection

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, protocol, emissions

I'm working on a toy device that goes into an airplane. It is using a BLE device and yet my knowledge about is a quite limited.

If I understood correctly, usually in protocols: the device advertise, the central connects and communicate. But if a disconnection happens (for instance my phone goes into flight mode), is it possible to be sure that the device doesn't send any data?(no advertising)

And more important: since I've been connected once, can my device just passively wait some incoming data to reconnect ? (the landing is done, my phone is active again. Thus I want to reconnect to my device without pushing any button)

I couldn't find any flowchart explaining this situation. Maybe that are silly questions but I cannot find the answer clearly.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Refer to the Bluetooth specs. They’re available from Bluetooth sig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And more important: since I've been connected once, can my device just passively wait some incoming data to reconnect

Nope. A BTLE peripherial *must* advertize in order to be found and re-connected.

Thus your device needs an OFF switch for strict airplane compliance.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. After several web search, I think you are right. It still seems to be a bit fuzzy, usage restrictions vary by airline.